# Ionic cordova - is this possible to run on device wireless?

Tags: cordova

When I am connecting the device and run:

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload
```

I can take off the cable and each reload will be doing wireless on the same WiFi.

But when I am working without the livereload, this wont work since the Cordova will deploy on the simulator and not on the device.

Is there a way to tell Cordova that I want to deploy on my device Id or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
ionic cordova run android --target="YOUR_DEVICE_TARGET_ID"
```

To list all the available devices, use :

```
ionic cordova run android --list
```