# Is there a way to deploy/debug a Cordova Android Ionic app through WiFi?

Tags: debugging, ionic-framework, deployment, usb, wifi

This is a twin of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596236/is-there-a-way-to-debug-a-cordova-ios-ionic-app-through-wifi) question (originally for iOS).

I would like to deploy and debug my Ionic app to an Android device connected via WiFi and not via USB with my PC, that is a device that I can reach just with WiFi.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic cordova - is this possible to run on device wireless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055793/ionic-cordova-is-this-possible-to-run-on-device-wireless)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course there is, provided that:

- you have Chrome installed
- you can plug-in your device via USB just ONCE.

If you can, in Windows you do like this

1. install **ADB** by executing [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0MKgCbUM0itSUhpUklCTFpzWkE&authuser=0) as administrator saying yes (Y) to everything
2. add ADB path to env variable (usually ADB is installed in the root so you do `PATH=%PATH%C:\adb;`)
3. install a [bash emulator](https://gitforwindows.org/)
4. USB plug-in the phone
5. open the bash emulator and execute in order
6. `ID=$(adb devices | awk -F'device' '{if (match($0, /device$/)) print $1}');`
7. `IP=$(adb shell ifconfig wlan0 | awk '{if (sub(/inet addr:/,"")) print $1 }');`
8. `adb tcpip 5555;`
9. `adb connect $IP:5555`

now you can deploy the app just using the regular `ionic cordova run android --device`: Ionic will deploy the app on the last device configured on points 6-9.

For the same reason you can debug on Chrome simply by navigating `chrome://inspect`, and click on the device with the `IP` equal to that of point 7.

I have found most of these information [here](https://remysharp.com/2016/12/17/chrome-remote-debugging-over-wifi). Thanks [Remy Sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4428009/remy-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect the device and the pc on the same network.
Then run `ionic run android —device -lc`
I don’t remember if you have to plug your device at least once for the build and then you can unplug and debug with WiFi maybe it’s not necessary.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not work. Steps done:
1) plug in my device via USB
2) connect the device on the same network of my pc
3) run ionic run android --device -lc [ deploy correctly done]
4) unplug the usb
5.A) ionic run android --device or alternatively
5.B) ionic run android --device --lc

in both cases 5.A and 5.B i get 'no devices found'